# Create file with java applet

Tags: java, html, applet

please, i've been struggling for days to get my applet to work, but i can't solve this
my goal is to write a file with the content of my html form
i'm able to reach the applet method, but it doesn't create the file
it's probably some issue with the certificate but i've tried several ways of using jarsigner found on tutorials, stackoverflow and videos, but none of them did the trick.

here is the process I'm following:

1 - create the applet

```
            public class Rappan extends Applet{
                public  String formResult;
                    public String generateFile(){

                        java.io.File file = new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/jsonResponse.txt");
                        try {
                            file.createNewFile();
                            FileWriter f = new FileWriter(file);
                            f.write(formResult);
                            f.close();
                            return "succeess!";

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            return "error!";

                        }


                    }
            }
```

2 - set my applet tag in html and my script to send the data:

```
            function getForm(str){
                appletRappan.formResult = str;
                var x = appletRappan.generateFile();
                alert(x);
            }
            $('form').submit(function(){
                var str = JSON.stringify($(this).serializeArray());
                getForm(str);
            });
```

3 - compile the class, css folder  and the html page into Rappan.jar file using:

```
            jar -cvfm Rappan.jar conf.txt Rappan.class css index.html
```

conf.txt content is
            Permissions: all-permissions
            Codebase: *
            Application-Name: Rappan

4 - generate a second and signed jar file using:

```
        jarsigner -signedjar SignedRappan.jar Rappan.jar rappankeytool
```

5 - run html in browser, fill the form, choose to run the application when popped up..
nothing happens after that.

I tried some other ways, like having a different folder with the html and css in my desktop, then i would compile only the class, copy both class and jar files into this folder and run the html.. Same result as before

I also changed generateFile() to init() method and ran in eclipse. In this case, the file was created.

just for the record, the appelt is supposed to be used to collect data from different users in different computers offline through a form and generate a file for each one..

I appreciate any help.

Comment: It's been a while since I wrote an applet but don't you need to invoke a security manager in your Java code in order to access the file system? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html

Comment: Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again.

Comment: both comments helped me to find out that java.security.accesscontrolexception access denied (java.util.propertypermission user.name read) is being thrown, so I followed this(http://geosim.cs.vt.edu/Java/MigModel/help/Policies.html) tutorial to create a policy file that should solve this exception.. but i'm still getting it